# Objects to file:how to?

Tags: java

```
public class Student {
    String name;
    int id;
    float grade;}

public class UndergraduateStudent  extends Student{
        float grade2;}


public class GraduateStudent  extends Student{
        float grade2,grade3;
        String supervizor;}
```

So I have the basic class Student which is extended to 2 more types.All the `Student` objects are stored in a SLL and now I have to store them into a file.How can I store them in the file if when extracted from the list,a cast to `(Student)` is done? I will need to get them back from the file so how will I know what type of student is each of the lines in the file?(I'm not interested for now in serialization)

Comment: "I'm not interested for now in serialization" - yes you are. You're talking about storing objects in a file. That *is* serialization.

Comment: YOu will have to use serialization. http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/09/08/reading-writing-objects-using-serialization/

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm required "a method to save the list of students into a 
text file" and after I do this comes the requirement of serialization

Comment: Saving objects to a file *is* serialization.

Comment: Serialization is conversion of an Object to output stream, saving an Object to a file via serialization is persistence

Comment: Please, if you want to store the information in a text file, edit the question to clarify that point.

Comment: So you want to store your list in a text file and read it back. Please show us your code for writing and reading and the specific problem you have. Is there any exception thrown?

Comment: What you are asking for is pretty convoluted without serialization. You can either use serialization or reinvent the wheel and write a big system for this yourself.

Comment: This question doesn't exhibit even the most basic understanding of the problem at hand. Serialization is what it's about, but the OP says he's not interested in serialization.

Comment: I found the answer and I posted it but I can't accept it today.

Answer (score 2):

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("file.ext");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(student);
oos.close();
```

or simply save this object like plain text file (ex CSV)

```
John, 102, 4.5
Mark, 103, 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your objects in xml and get your object back in from there.
Probably you can use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your class serializable

```
public class Student implements java.io.Serializable
```

Read the article - [Java Serialization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm)

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for was something like this:

```
public void writeTofile() throws IOException{

    File file = new File("./StudentRepo.txt");
    if (!file.exists())
        file.createNewFile();
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        Student[] copy = this.getStudents();
        for (Student st : copy){
            bw.write(st.toString() + "\n");
        }
        bw.close();
 }
```